# Play SkyRadio with JW Player

Tags: javascript, api, audio, stream, jwplayer

I would like to use the JW Player to play one of these streams from SkyRadio:

```
http://www.skyradio.nl/player/skyradio.asx
http://www.skyradio.nl/player/skyradionl.pls
http://8623.live.streamtheworld.com:80/SKYNLAAC_SC
```

I have tried to look at the document all yesterday but no lucks http://support.jwplayer.com/

Hope anybody can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use JW Player to display someone else's content. You can display your own streams, your own hosted videos, or publicly-available YouTube videos. That's it - nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
<div id='playerUyHYwyQDukeC'></div>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('playerUyHYwyQDukeC').setup({
            file: 'http://8623.live.streamtheworld.com/SKYRADIOAAC?streamtheworld_user=1&nobuf=1427147101030',
            type: 'flv',
            width: '100%',
            aspectratio: '16:9',
            primary: 'flash',
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are not supported steams by the JW Player. We only support the following - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

Answer (score 0):

@Ethan 
file is FLV format which is supported by Jw Player i think

```
http://8623.live.streamtheworld.com/SKYRADIOAAC?streamtheworld_user=1&nobuf=1427147101030
```